# C++ - avoiding the implicit inlining of a function defined in the class definition

Tags: c++

In my implementation files (.cc files), I often find that it's convenient to define member functions in class definitions (such as the functions of a Pimpl class). For example:

```
struct X::Impl {
    void DoSomething() {
        ...
    }
};
```

instead of

```
struct X::Impl {
    void DoSomething();
};

void X::Impl::DoSomething() {
    ...
}
```

I think this is preferable to implementing the function outside of the class definition for several reasons. It enhances readability and facilitates the practice of keeping methods small (by making it easy to add them). The code is also easier to maintain since you never have to update method declarations.

The only downside I see is that methods defined in the class declaration are implicitly inlined, which is not usually desirable because of the increase in the size of the object code.

My questions are:

1. Do I have this right? Are there other downsides to this practice that I'm missing?
2. Is the implicit inlining something to worry about? Is the compiler smart enough to reject my implicit request to inline methods that shouldn't be inlined?
3. Is it possible (via compiler extensions or otherwise) to declare that a method defined in the class definition not be inlined?

Comment: It's not more readable, and the idea that functions should be small comes from professors, not the real world.  It's a bogus rule.

Comment: GCC has `-fno-inline` but I think turning that off would be silly and I trust gcc to make a far smarter decision than I would.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Agreed. It is important to note that the C++ code of the functions *should be* small for readability purposes, but the generated code need not be. Let the compiler do what it knows best.

Comment: Also if you put the pimpl definition right in the header its not really a pimpl is ot?

Comment: <joke>maybe we can propose a new 'outline' keyword for C++27</joke>

Comment: @John: Small functions are easy to test, self-documenting, and easier to manage. I learned this from the real world -- not professors. Also, no one ever said anything about putting anything in a header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that you should not care. Member functions defined within the class definition are implicitly `inline`, but that does not mean that they are *inlined* (i.e. the code need not be inlined at the place of call).

Compiler implementors have dedicated quite a bit of time and resources to come up with heuristics that determine whether actual inlining should be done or not, based on the size of the function, the complexity and whether it can be inlined at all or not (a recursive function cannot be inlined<sup>[*]</sup>). The compiler has more information on the generated code and the architecture in which it will run than most of us have. Trust it, then if you feel that there might be an issue, profile, and if profiling indicates that you should change the code, do it, but make an informed decision *after the fact*.

If you want to verify whether the function has actually be *inlined* or not, you can look at the assembly and check whether there are calls to the function or the code was really inlined.

---

<sup>[*]</sup> If the compiler can transform the recursion into iteration, as is the case in tail recursion, then the transformed function could be theoretically be inlined. But then, functions with loops have lesser probabilities of being inlined anyway...

Comment: Exactly, and you can usually specify the recursion depth too, boost::xpressive makes heavy use of that for example. In fact I usually write new classes in a single .h file, when I find the class useful I create an accompanying .cpp file.

Comment: While you should not care if a function is inlined or not, you should probably care that a function definition in a header has the `inline` keyword, as it prevents multiple definition linker errors if you include the header file in more than one translation unit.  The `inline` keyword says, "Hey, linker!  This function definition might be included in 2, 3 or 42 translation units.  Make sure you use only one definition for all of them."

Answer (score 2):

I don't know portable way of preventing inlining, but with GCC you can use attribute. For example:

```
struct X::Impl {
    void DoSomething() __attribute__((noinline)) {
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add up all the CPU time that will ever be saved by your inlining choices.  Spend less than that of your own on them.  Linear pathlength worries are for paths handling now trillions of executions a day.  Four billion is near enough a second out of L1. 250 times that isn't five minutes. If nobody's complaining about performance, your and your compiler's choices are at least playing in the right league.

Opinions on readability differ widely.  It's your audience's opinion that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the compiler will inline whatever it pleases, and it won't pay too much attention to any `inline` keywords given by the programmer. `inline` is usually treated more or less the same as `static`.

For example, a recursive function can usually not be completely inlined (the function body you'd inline will contain again a call that should be inlined). To test the behavior of your specific compiler, you could for example define a class like this:

```
class Fib {
public:      
   int calc(int i);
};

int Fib::calc(int i) {
  if (i > 1)
     return calc(i-1) + calc(i-2);
  return 1;
}
```

With this definition, a sample program like the following would not be compilable in reasonable time or size if the compiler would feel obligated to inline all calls to `calc`:

```
#include "tst.hpp"
#include <iostream>                
int main() {
   Fib f;
   std::cout << f.calc(1000) << std::endl;
};
```

So you can test you compilers behavior by compiling this program. If compilation succeeds, the compiler didn't inline all calls to `Fib::calc`.